# How can I prevent a null RequestParam raising an exception?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, kotlin, null

I'm working in a Spring Boot environnement using Kotlin. I made a controller with a method annotated with @GetMapping. This method have some parameters of type @RequestParam declared as Double type. If I try to call my method without providing these parameters, my code raises the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional double parameter 'latitude' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type.
```

I assume that the parameters have default value (probably 0.0), but Kotlin need an object which can be null, so the exception is raised.

All works fine if I provide the parameters, but I want my code working if no parameters are provided.

How can I avoid this exception?

Here's how my controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/stations")
class StationController {

    @GetMapping
            fun findAll(@RequestParam(value = "latitude", required = false) currentLatitude: Double,
                        @RequestParam(value = "longitude", required = false) currentLongitude: Double): ResponseEntity<List<Entity>> {
                //Method body
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following part of [the documentation regarding basic types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation) will help you:

> On the Java platform, numbers are physically stored as JVM primitive types, unless we need a nullable number reference (e.g. Int?) or generics are involved. In the latter cases numbers are boxed.

Your guess might be correct then. Try using `Double?` and it should be ok.

Comment: I feel ashamed that I didn't think about that sooner. Thank you for your help.